# How do tidal forces on incomplete geodesics determine extendability?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, geodesics, tidal-effect

Why can we be sure that the manifold with the metric $(M,g)$ does not have a geodesically complete extension if it has an incomplete timelike geodesic along which the tidal force blows up? Does this mean it cannot be (properly) extended full stop or just not extended
to a geodesically complete semi-Riemannian manifold? (For example in Schwarzschild case)

Comment: It's not uncommon for spacetimes to have extensions which are not spacetimes (usually because you cannot extend the metric tensor there). If a spacetime is geodesically incomplete due to curvature blow up, it could have such an extension as a smooth manifold, or it could even have an extension with a distributional metric, or it could have no extension at all, at least not as a manifold.

Comment: Physicists are obsessed with mathematically extending spacetime manifolds, but even when such an extension is possible, it does t mean it is physical or exists in reality.